# Getting background color from view model property

Tags: maui

Is it possible to get a control’s background color from a property in ViewModel?

The purpose is to be able to change color of `Border` or `Button` based on user actions. Because I’m using the MVVM approach, ideally, I simply set the background color of my control through a property in my view model.

I tried the following but it didn’t work:

```xml
<Border
   BackgroundColor="{Binding MyBorderBackgroundColor}">
    <Label Text=“Hello World” />
</Border>
```

In my view model, I use a `string` property and set it to either a color name such as `Red` or a Hex value such as `#FF0000`. I have an `Init()` method that I call from `OnAppearing()` and set the value -- see below:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
string myBorderBackgroundColor;
    
...
    
public void Init()
{
   MyBorderBackgroundColor = "Red"; // Or Hex value => MyBorderBackgroundColor = "#FF0000";
}
```

The app simply ignores the color setting and defaults to page background. No error but just doesn't use the value set through the view model property.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Define “didn’t work” any errors? Also, what does your backing property look like?

Comment: App simply ignores it. No error but doesn't use it. I updated the original post with more details.

Comment: Why do you want to define the colors in the ViewModel? Can't you use triggers? If you need to set the colors from within the ViewModel, then you may want to use the `Color` type instead of `string`: `[ObservableProperty]
Color myBorderBackgroundColor;`

Comment: @Sam BTW, in your sample code, it should be `BackgroundColor="{Binding MyBorderBackgroundColor}"`, you forgot the quotes there

Comment: You may use ```MyBorderBackgroundColor=Color.FromHex("#2B0B98")``` or ```MyBorderBackgroundColor = Colors.Yellow``` such like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your backing property is a `string`, while it should be a `Color`. However, I do understand you would think this works, because in XAML you can simply add a string to it.

### Background

To understand why that works in XAML but not code, we'll have to learn about `TypeConverter`. Since XAML can only contain strings, we have to find a way to convert that string into a type that is actually useable. With a `TypeConverter` we do just that.

On an object where we expect people to use a string in XAML but still expect the desired outcome we add this attribute, here it is for [`Color`](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Graphics/src/Graphics/Color.cs):

```cs
[TypeConverter(typeof(Converters.ColorTypeConverter))]
public class Color
{
   /// The class
}
```

Here is the [full implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Graphics/src/Graphics/Converters/ColorTypeConverter.cs) of `ColorTypeConverter` in case you're curious.

This means that when the XAML parser finds this property and the corresponding (string) value, it will invoke that `TypeConverter` first and that results into the concrete type, in our case `Color`, to be used.

When you do a binding like you're doing, the `TypeConverter` is not invoked, and thus we're now binding a string value to a property that expects a `Color` object and therefore: not working.

### The Fix

To fix this, change the backing property to a `Color` and initialize it as such.

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
Color myBorderBackgroundColor;

// ...
    
public void Init()
{
   MyBorderBackgroundColor = Colors.Red; // Or Hex value => MyBorderBackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#FF0000");
}
```

Your XAML contains a small error with no quotes around the binding. Not sure if that is in your actual code, but just to be sure. Make sure there is quotes around the value of `BackgroundColor` like so:

```xml
<Border
   BackgroundColor="{Binding MyBorderBackgroundColor}">
    <Label Text="Hello World" />
</Border>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to make sure that the binding is set up correctly using double quotes:

```xml
<Border
   BackgroundColor="{Binding MyBorderBackgroundColor}">
    <Label Text=“Hello World” />
</Border>
```

Then, I would recommend using the `Color` type in the ViewModel instead of a `string` since there is no implicit conversion between those types. That's how I am doing it in my own apps, too.

So, you could change your code to the following and define the color in a variety of different ways (the list is not final):

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
Color myBorderBackgroundColor;
    
//...
    
public void Init()
{
   // use hex value
   MyBorderBackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#FF0000");

   // parse string
   MyBorderBackgroundColor = Color.Parse("Red");

   // use RGB
   MyBorderBackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(255,0,0);

   // use named color
   MyBorderBackgroundColor = Colors.Red;

   //...
}
```

You can find more information about Colors in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/colors).